# Web scraping using rvest

Tags: rvest

I want to scrape all the text in the following website:
http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=49703&pageIndex=0&doclang=en&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=656172

My code:

```
  html = http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=49703&pageIndex=0&doclang=en&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=656172

  main_content <- html_nodes(html, css = "#document_content")
  main_text <- main_content  %>% html_nodes("p") %>%html_text()
```

However, in this way, not all the text are extracted because some text is in the node "dd"..."/dd"

I wonder if I can do something like  html_nodes("p") or html_nodes("dd") or html_nodes("dt") to replace html_nodes("p") in the above dode.

How can I achieve this? Or is there any other way I can accomplish my task? Ideally, I dont want to use

```
  main_text <- main_content   %>% html_text()
```

because I want to separate each sentence.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting css, if you separate the nodes you want by a comma, that is like a logical OR...

```
library("rvest")
url = "http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=49703&pageIndex=0&doclang=en&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=656172"
page <- read_html(url)
main_text <- page %>% 
  html_nodes("#document_content") %>% 
  html_nodes("p,dd,dt") %>%
  html_text()
```